# Record audio from AirPod microphone

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to record and speech recognize the audio coming through the microphone of my bluetooth AirPods.

I tried everything I found but with no luck. I'm able to record from the built in microphone but as soon as I set the audio category to bluetooth it crashes.

This is the current version of my code:

```
askSpeechPermission()

var request = SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest()
var listOfInputs = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().availableInputs

do {
     try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord, mode: AVAudioSessionModeDefault, options: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.allowBluetooth)
} catch {

}

let node = audioEngine.inputNode
let recordingFormat = node.outputFormat(forBus: 0)

node.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat) { buffer, _ in
    self.request.append(buffer)
}
```

And this is the resulting crash error.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'required condition is false: format.sampleRate == hwFormat.sampleRate'

Comment: please add 'func' and your missing '{' ....

Answer (score 2):

Have u tried to check your sample rate. To modify your Sample rate you can use

```
let fmt = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat32, sampleRate: 44100, channels: 1, interleaved: true)
```

and then you can it to your format

```
node.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: fmt) { buffer, _ in
    self.request.append(buffer)
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it keeps crashing on the installTap with the same old error.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem and I solved adding the BluetoothA2DP option:

```
audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
              withOptions:(AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth | AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker | AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetoothA2DP)
                    error:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what worked for me. My use case is very similar to that of OP, so I had just set the category to `record` and in options listed on `allowBluetooth`, because I'm not interested in playing audio at all, only capturing and processing it.

But for some reason it would not capture audio from Airpods with just those settings defined.

Answer (score 1):

Follow Osman suggestion, I can fix the problem by set the sample rate as the AudioSession sample rate

```
let sampleRate = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().sampleRate
let fmt = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat32, sampleRate: sampleRate, channels: 1, interleaved: true)
node.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: fmt) { buffer, _ in
    self.request.append(buffer)
}
```

Hope this help someone~